# Multiplying 3D matrix

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

I was wondering if it is possible to multiply a 3D matrix (say a cube $n\times n\times n$) to a matrix of dimension $n\times 1$? If yes, then how. Maybe you can suggest some resources which I can read to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If you view the $n\times n\times n$ object as $n$ different $n\times n$ matrices, then you can apply each one to the $n\times 1$ vector, yielding $n$ different $n\times1$ vectors, which could be viewed as a $n\times n$ matrix.

This won't have interesting multiplication properties though beyond those that come from the regular matrix-vector multiplication.

Comment: what do you think the dimensions of the resultant be?

Comment: An $n\times n$ array - It's kind of like this: $(n\times n\times \color{red}{n})(\color{red}{n}\times 1)\to(n\times n\times 1)$.

Answer (score 7):

Multiplication of regular matrices arises from their interpretation as linear transformations. For a square matrix you get a map $T:V\to V$ (after having chosen a basis for $V$.) Since the domain and range of $T$ are the same, you can compose linear transformations, and this gives you matrix multiplication.

A cubical matrix can correspond to a linear map $V\to V\otimes V$ or $V\otimes V\to V$ (or a number of other possibilities such as $V\otimes V\otimes V\to \mathbb R$). (As Milind points out, this type of thing is called a tensor, and the different possibilities correspond to different placement of the indices up or down on the tensor, $t^i_{jk}, t^{ij}_k, t_{ijk}$, etc.

An $n\times 1$ matrix can represent a map from $V$ to $\mathbb R$. So if you think of the 3D array as a map from $V\otimes V\to V$, then you can compose it with the map $V\to\mathbb R$. The resulting map is a map $V\otimes V\to \mathbb R$, which can be thought of as an $n\times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 4):

[Tensors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) are very relevant to your question, as they can be represented as multi-dimensional arrays.

A tensor product of a order 3 tensor (the $n \times n\times n$ cube) and a 1st order tensor (the $n\times 1$ vector) will give you a tensor of order 4 (i.e. a 4-dimensional array).

Comment: I've never studied tensors, but wikipedia states that "The tensor product of (finite dimensional) vector spaces has dimension equal to the product of the dimensions of the two factors".  Is this statement incorrect?